# How do i add LocRotScale Keyframe?

Tags: animation

[image: LocRotScale]

Hello, i need to add the LocRotScale keyframe, i have no clue how to add it, and when i search it, i end up with results as to how to add locrotscale to other keyframes, which i know how to.
The problem is, the RIG was in a ba dposition when i made the animations, and now i will have to move all of them, unless i add this keyframe, because that seems to work with the other rig.

Comment: This LocRotScale is an object or a bone in your rig, what not necessary to exist in every case, so we don't know what is it. Please share your file.